# Is cadastre data for Italy publicly available for download?

Tags: geospatial, italy, cadastral

I am looking for a website where I may be able to enter the numbers of pieces of land and would be able to find some cadastre data, i.e. at least

- size of the plot (square meters)
- possibly shape and neighbouring plots
- buildings

I would need this for certain places in Italy.

Answer (score 1):

Geodati.gov.it lists Cadastral cartography by munipality. However, all of the links to download ("scarica") these files are grayed out. Each file lists a website and some contact information, so you may be able to request these as downloads. They also provide an XML file, so you may be able to add these to a GIS project as WMS layers.

Here's a link to the [google-translated page](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=it&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=http://geodati.gov.it/geoportale/visualizzazione-metadati%3Fkeyword%3DINSPIRETheme:%2522Parcelle%2520catastali%2522&xid=25657,15700019,15700043,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700186,15700190,15700201&usg=ALkJrhi4R_rnSM6dL4Zs-WupH8T3opYe_g).

If that won't load, go to http://geodati.gov.it/geoportale/ and click on *Dati di base topografic e catastali*, then click on *Parcelle catastali*. [Here's a direct link.](http://geodati.gov.it/geoportale/visualizzazione-metadati?keyword=INSPIRETheme:%22Parcelle%20catastali%22)

There's also a [map viewer ("Vizzualizatore")](http://geodati.gov.it/geoportale/geoviewer/). This seems like it would allow you to see the parcel/cadastre layers, but I couldn't figure out how.

I found this site by translating "real estate" (immobiliare), "parcel" (appezzamento) and "download" (scaricare) into Italian, then googling shapefile scaricare appezzamento immobiliare.

I know this isn't *exactly* what you were looking for, but I hope it helps you get closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can register to https://sister.agenziaentrate.gov.it/Main/index.jsp.

Feel free to ask if you need further help.